# Selecting Maximum Value frm the column and adding up multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Named "Patients" which looks like

```
  PatientName    DateOftest    Eye     L1    L2    L3    L4     L5
    Mike         17-02-2009     L      23    25    40    32     30
    Mike         17-02-2009     R      25    30    34    35     24
    Bill         08-03-2006     L      20    24    30    24     25
    Bill         08-03-2006     R      18    25    27    30     24
```

Now, Iam after results which will select Patient Name and Dateoftest and eye as "Binocular" and "Sum" which is the sum of the highest values of L1,L2,L3,L4,L5 on that  Test date..

Results:

```
  PatientName    DateOftest      Eye          Sum
    Mike         17-02-2009    Binocular      160    
    Bill         08-03-2006    Binocular      130
```

Here "sum" is sum of Highest values from Left and Right Eye of Mike which is 160 and Bill is 130.

Comment: Im after Something Like                                              select  PatientName, DateOfTest, Eye as "Binocular", Max(L1)+Max(L2)+Max(L3)+Max(L4)+Max(L5) as SUM where Distinct (PatientName and DateofTest);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    PatientName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    DateOfTest  date NOT NULL,
    Eye         char(1) NOT NULL,
    L1          tinyint NOT NULL,
    L2          tinyint NOT NULL,
    L3          tinyint NOT NULL,
    L4          tinyint NOT NULL,
    L5          tinyint NOT NULL
)

INSERT @Data
VALUES 
    ('Mike', '20090217', 'L', 23, 25, 40, 32, 30),
    ('Mike', '20090217', 'R', 25, 30, 34, 35, 24),
    ('Bill', '20060308', 'L', 20, 24, 30, 24, 25),
    ('Bill', '20060308', 'R', 18, 25, 27, 30, 24);

SELECT
    d.PatientName,
    d.DateOfTest,
    Eye = 'Binocular',
    [Sum] = MAX(L1) + MAX(L2) + MAX(L3) + MAX(L4) + MAX(L5)
FROM @Data AS d
GROUP BY
    d.PatientName,
    d.DateOfTest;
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT PatientName, DateOfTest, "Binocular" AS Eye,
         MAX(L1 + L2 + L3 + L4 + L5) AS [Sum]
    FROM Patients
GROUP BY PatientName, DateOfTest, Eye
```

Comment: The maximum value should not be from entire columns of L1,L2,L3,L4 and L5.. only for the particular test date.. here the maximum values on test date for mike are.. 25+25+40+35+30 which is 160. and for Bill ..20+25+30+30+25 which is 130..

Comment: Then see SQL Kiwi's response. It wasn't entirely clear from the question that you were looking for the maximum values of *each* of L1, L2, L3 ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT PatientName, 
   DateOfTest,
   MAX(L1) + MAX(L2) + MAX(L3) + MAX(L4) + MAX(L5) SummedVal,
   'Binocular' Eye
FROM Patients
GROUP BY PatientName, DateOfTest, Eye
```

Here's a quick [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d166b/2).

And please note the difference in using MAX(L1+L2...) vs MAX(L1) + MAX(L2) ... -- the first won't produce your correct results.

Good luck.

Comment: The maximum value should not be from entire columns of L1,L2,L3,L4 and L5.. only for the particular test date.. here the maximum values on test date for mike are.. 25+25+40+35+30 which is 160. and for Bill ..20+25+30+30+25 which is 130..

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help.. But i need maximum values for particular date and particular patient.. not for entire columns of L1..

Answer (score 0):

This will not search on entire column this will search max value for particular date and particular patient.because we have use group by here.

```
select PatientName,
       DateOftest,
       Max(L1)+Max(L2)+Max(L3)+Max(L4)+Max(L5) as Sum,
      'Binocular' Eye 
from table 
group by PatientName,DateOftest,Eye
```